# Confirm preceding and following sibling in XPATH

Tags: python, selenium

I've got the below statement to check that 2 conditions exist in a
an element:

```
 if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$400.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Buy']")) > 0:
   elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$400.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Buy']")
```

I've tried a few variations, including "preceding sibling::span[text()='x'", but can't seem to get the syntax correct or if I'm going about it the right way.

HTML is below. the current find_elements(By.XPATH...) correctly finds the "Total" and "Buy" class, I would like to add $20.00 in the "price" class as a condition also.

```
    <ul>
       <li class="List">
           <div class="List-Content row">
               <div class="Price">"$20.00"</div>
               <div class="Quantity">10</div>
               <div class="Change">0%</div>
               <div class="Total">
                   <span>$400.00</span>
               </div>
               <div class="Buy">
                   <a class="Button">Buy</a>
               </div>
           </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Share the URL. If not possible update the question with HTML code.

Comment: Need to see HTML to help you further.

Comment: Have update with HTML. Thanks!

Comment: *I would like to add $20.00 in the "price" class as a condition also.* - can you please explain ?

Comment: General remark: `text()` does not do what you apparently think it does. Don't use it to search for elements by text content. Use `.` instead (e.g. `span[. = '$400.00']`, `a[. = 'Buy']`) or use the element directly (e.g. `//*[span = '$400.00']/following-sibling::div/...`).

Comment: Hi @balderman - currently the formula searches a unordered list with 100 of list items. It first searches for a total div that = "$400.00" to identify the correct list item, and then checks to confirm that the associated button with this li is "buy"...it is confirmed with a length that is >0  if both conditions are met. I would like to add an additional condition in the div titled 'price' ...Price is in the same li class as identified by "total" earlier. In this case $20.00 would meet this condition. If not, then the len != >0.

Comment: @user1345331 So would you like to get The 'Total' value where 'Buy' value is 'Buy' and Price is 20 ?

Comment: @balderman Apologies, to give you more context, if the if statement returns true, then the next line of code finds the "buy" button using essentially the same logic, except uses find_element instead of  find_elements... I've updated the code in the original post to reflect this

Comment: @balderman Essentially I am trying to find the link if those two conditions from the same <li> are met ($400.00, link text ="buy"). I am trying to add a third condition, if price =$20.00

Comment: @user1345331 My answer's code uses ElemenTree to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using built in ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


html = '''<li class="List">
   <div class="List-Content row">
       <div class="Price">"$20.00"</div>
       <div class="Quantity">10</div>
       <div class="Change">0%</div>
       <div class="Total"><span>$400.00</span></div>
       <div class="Buy"><a class="Button">Buy</a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="List-Content row">
       <div class="Price">"$27.00"</div>
       <div class="Quantity">10</div>
       <div class="Change">0%</div>
       <div class="Total"><span>$400.00</span></div>
       <div class="Buy"><a class="Button">Buy</a></div>
   </div>
</li>'''

items = {'Total':'$400.00','Buy':'Buy','Price':'"$20.00"'}

root = ET.fromstring(html)
first_level_divs = root.findall('div')
for first_level_div in first_level_divs:
    results = {}
    for k,v in items.items():
        div = first_level_div.find(f'.div[@class="{k}"]')
        one_level_down = len(list(div)) > 0
        results[k] = list(div)[0].text if one_level_down else div.text
    if results == items:
        print('found')
    else:
        print('not found')
    results = {}
```

output

```
found
not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML snippet

```html
<ul>
   <li class="List">
       <div class="List-Content row">
           <div class="Price">"$20.00"</div>
           <div class="Quantity">10</div>
           <div class="Change">0%</div>
           <div class="Total"><span>$400.00</span></div>
           <div class="Buy"><a class="Button">Buy</a></div>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would use this XPath:

```
buy_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, """//div[
    contains(@class, 'List-Content')
    and div[@class = 'Price'] = '$20.00'
    and div[@class = 'Total'] = '$400.00'
]//a[. = 'Buy']""")

for buy_button in buy_buttons:
   print(buy_button)
```

The `for` loop replaces your `if len(buy_buttons) > 0` check. It won't run when there are no results, so the `if` is superfluous.

Comment: Cheers Tomalak - any reason there are the """ quotation marks? Are they supposed to be comments?

Comment: @user1345331 No, they are not comments. They are multi-line strings. It's just a convention that they are used as comments, here I'm using them to increase readability of the XPath statement.

Comment: Ok great, thanks! The code is running, but wasn't returning what I expect. If I take out the loop and print buy_buttons, it returns "[]" ...... Any ideas? there were a couple of indentations on my HTML which i've updated, but wouldn't think that would have affected it.

Comment: @user1345331 If you have to trim the element text before comparing, use `normalize-space()`, e.g. `and normalize-space(div[@class = 'Total']) = '$400.00'`.